# A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, jquery-easyui

**DB MetersTree TABLE**

```
id       text   parentId    state

 0       root          0     open
 1    level 1          1     open
 2    level 1          1     open
 ...
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public ActionResult GetDemoTree()
{
    OsosPlus2DbEntities entity = new OsosPlus2DbEntities();
    MetersTree meterTree = entity.MetersTree.FirstOrDefault();

    return Json(meterTree, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**DATA FORMAT THAT SHOULD BE** (for example)

```
[{  
    "id": 1,  
    "text": "Node 1",  
    "state": "closed",  
    "children": [{  
        "id": 11,  
        "text": "Node 11"  
    },{  
        "id": 12,  
        "text": "Node 12"  
    }]  
},{  
    "id": 2,  
    "text": "Node 2",  
    "state": "closed"  
}]
```

How can I create tree Json Data? If I write MetersTree with its relationships I get the error that is defined in the title.

Comment: Can you show the content of the MetersTree Model?

Comment: It is generated by EntitiyFramework from db_table that I write above. Also, parentId refrence to the id. I know what is the problem, But I dont know , how Can I fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it like this:

**VIEW MODEL**

```
public class MetersTreeViewModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public bool @checked { get; set; }
    public string attributes { get; set; }
    public List<MetersTreeViewModel> children { get; set; }
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public ActionResult GetMetersTree()
{
    MetersTree meterTreeFromDb = entity.MetersTree.SingleOrDefault(x => x.sno == 5); //in my db this is the root.
    List<MetersTreeViewModel> metersTreeToView = buildTree(meterTreeFromDb.Children).ToList();

    return Json(metersTreeToView, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**BuildTree Method**

```
private List<MetersTreeViewModel> BuildTree(IEnumerable<MetersTree> treeFromDb)
{
    List<MetersTreeViewModel> metersTreeNodes = new List<MetersTreeViewModel>();
    foreach (var node in treeFromDb)
    {
        if (node.Children.Any())
        {
            metersTreeNodes.Add(new MetersTreeViewModel
            {
                id = node.sno,
                text = node.Text,
                state = node.Text,
                children = BuildTree(node.Children)
            });
        }
        else {
            metersTreeNodes.Add(new MetersTreeViewModel
            {
                id = node.sno,
                text = node.Text,
                state = node.Text
            });
        }
    }

    return metersTreeNodes;
}
```

Thanks to all who are interested in ...

Answer (score 3):

You need to break the circular reference that is being picked up because of the navigational property in your EF class.

You can map the results into an anonymous type like this, although this is untested:

```
public ActionResult GetDemoTree()
{
    OsosPlus2DbEntities entity = new OsosPlus2DbEntities();
    MetersTree meterTree = entity.MetersTree.FirstOrDefault();

    var result = from x in meterTree
           select new 
            {
            x.id,
            x.text,
            x.state,
            children = x.children.Select({
                c => new {
                    c.id,
                    c.text
                })
         };

    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: OK, see my update. I'm flying blind here, but I've selected the children into another anonymous type that removes the circular reference

Comment: your suggestion is working. But there is a problem. In fact, I need circular refrence to get last node of tree. in your suggestion, I can get two level of tree. In my tree, there may be a lot of level. Thanks for reply

Comment: I wonder, Should I get all tree nodes, and in foreach, I create a tree, dynamicly?

Comment: OK, well I guess I answered your question, but your question wasn't quite right :) - glad you got it solved.

Comment: how do you fix it when you return View instead of Json?

Comment: @batmaci The same fix should still apply, you just need to `return View("ViewName", result)` from your Action instead of the `Json(...)` object I think.